# create new column based unique values

Tags: r, calculated-columns

Say I have a simple dataset of this

```
set.seed(123)
a <- sample(1:4, 30, replace = TRUE)
b <- sample(5:10, 30, replace = TRUE)
c <- sample(5:15, 30, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

Now I want to create a new column, `data$d` which will take the values of `b` when `a`=1|3 and the values of `c` when `a`=2|4

Comment: `data$d <-  with(data, ifelse(a %in% c(1,3), b, c))`

Comment: Please update your post with the relevant example and expected output.

Comment: Are you looking for `data$d <- data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), data$a + 1)]` ? I hope you do realize your question is very unclear and you changed it completely from the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, supposing column `a`  only have values in `c(1,2,3,4)`:

```
data$d = ifelse(data$a==1|data$a==3, data$b, data$c)
```